AWS CloudWatch Agent - Block Default Log Groups from Being Created
I am using Elastic Beanstalk and want to stream a custom application log to CloudWatch, which I am now successfully doing.
However, default log groups are being created, and I only want my custom application logs to be sent to Cloudwatch. What is the correct method to stop default CloudWatch Log group being generated?
The Default log groups :
/var/log/eb-engine.log
/var/log/eb-hooks.log
/var/log/httpd/access_log
/var/log/httpd/error_log
/var/log/nginx/access.log
/var/log/nginx/error.log

I have tried to use IAM permissions to block the creation of these log groups:
AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier - Has the following:
{
    "Sid": "CloudWatchLogsAccess",
    "Action": [
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
        "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk*"
    ]
}

I have tried overriding with my own inline policy; however, default log groups are still being created.
My policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk/*/var/log/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

After delete the log groups and restarting my EB environment. The default log groups are created again.
